# URL to a portal application

Tags: portal, websphere-portal

When a portal application is run using RAD/ or any IDE, the portal server will generate a random URL for the application, which expires after some time.

If I had an portal application like HelloWorld, how do I get a permanent URL like:

myportal/**HelloWorld**/

instead of a randomly generated URL. This question could also be asked like, how can I get a unique URL to my portal application

Comment: Java EE Web Context Root can be set to a friendly name, in WebCenter Portal.

There should be something similar in WebSphere Portal as well.

Answer (score 0):

When you go to place a portlet in a more permanent place in your Portal, you will create the page yourself rather than letting RAD generate something random for you. Part of the options for a page is a friendly URL. So you could specify what URL you want after the /wps/myportal/. Here is a link to some basic documentation about [creating pages](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20WebSphere%20Portal%208%20Product%20Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Page_creation_and_navigation_wp8&content=pdcontent).

Answer (score 0):

If you want smth like /wps/myportal/HelloWorld you need create portal page and give it friendly name. Then you can deploy and place you portlet application(s) on this page.

If you to have application outside portal context (servlet for example), you need deploy it to WAS directly and set desired context root to get yourserver:10039/your/app/context